# Javascript Scale(x,y) method doesn't work on Canvas with negative parameter

Tags: javascript, canvas, scale, drawimage

I am trying to flip an image using the scale() method.
I have this code:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(-1, 1);

ctx.drawImage(Img, 0, 0, 100, 100);

ctx.restore();
```

When I put 1, 1 into the scale parameter, or any other real number, the scale function works fine. But once I put a negative parameter such as -1 (to flip image horizontally) the image doesn't draw at all. The code is in a function with a 12 fps setInterval. I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find a solution. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yong/ZJQX5/ :)

Comment: Your flipped image is being drawn off the canvas. Reset the x,y in your drawImage so that the image is pulled back on the canvas.

Comment: Ah, so the image coordinates were transferred into the negative dimension :O Works like a charm now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

as being said by markE, whenever you scale, rotate or transform the canvas, the coordinates you are using will react to the change in the canvas transformation - in your case sending the image off the canvas. In order to flip the image in place, you should consider using translate with the width of the image as first parameter:

```
ctx.save();

//The scale will flip the whole canvas, and will move the image 
//to the left (by the image width size)
ctx.scale(-1, 1);

//Using translate to move the image back to it's original origin
ctx.translate(Img.width, 0)

ctx.drawImage(Img, 0, 0, 100, 100);

ctx.restore();
```